# Putting the power of vim into WMs: Modal Window Management?

Tags: vim, window, window-managers

I'm a huge fan of Vim, and I largely adhere to the extremely efficient modal editing style. After some experience with Vim, I decided to get into other software that shared its philosophy on efficient/speedy keyboard usage. This naturally led me to [tiling window managers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager), which allows one to efficiently manage window space, workspaces/tags, multiple screens, etc. all with keyboard shortcuts.

It seems a large majority of users of TWMs use Vim, so I was wondering why there isn't a Vim-like window manager? By this, I mean rather than use some awkwardly-placed modifiers to manage windows, there is a specific mode you must enter from which all window management is simply a keystroke away.

That way, you can do all your manipulation by entering, say `wm` mode, hit all your manipulations with single keystrokes, and exit `wm`. Does such a window management style exist, and if not, well why not?

Comment: Vim doesn't work like that either and most WMs provide default shortcuts that are quite close to `<C-w>j` and friends. Or are you referring to `:wincmd j` which is not a mode? I find that using the `<Windows>`/`<Super>` key as prefix for all window related operation quite easy.